# ng-click not executing controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a very simple function in one of my angular controllers

```
$scope.search = function () {
    alert("Search");  
};
```

and from my view I have

```
<button type="button" data-ng-click="search()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

The function is never executed when the button is clicked, but the rest of the code in my controller is executed as expected. Is there any reason why the ng-click directive will not fire my function?

I have similar controllers all working as expected.

**Update**

The button is within a bootstrap 3 modal, when the button is moved out of the modal, the click event works. Any reason for this happening?

**Update**

The button is within scope of the controller, here is my controller and view for clarity

```
(function () {
var module = angular.module("crest");

var brokerGridController = function ($scope, readEndpoint, readBroker) {
    $scope.endpoint = "";
    $scope.isBusy = false;
    $scope.havebroker = false;
    $scope.brokers = [];
    $scope.searchCriteria = "";
    $scope.exception = "";

    var setEndpoint = function (response) {
        $scope.endpoint = response.Endpoint;
    };

    readEndpoint.read("BusinessLogicAPI").then(setEndpoint);

    var onSuccess = function (response) {
        if (response.Message.MessageType == 1) {
            onError();
        }

        $scope.havebrokers = response.brokers.length > 0;

        angular.copy(response.brokers, $scope.brokers);
        angular.copy(response.Message.body, $scope.exception);
    };

    var onError = function () {
        $("#errorMessageModal").modal("show");
    };

    $scope.search = function () {
        alert("Search");
    };
};

module.controller("brokerGridController", ["$scope", "readEndpoint", "readBroker", brokerGridController]);
}());
```

and the view

```
<div data-ng-controller="brokerGridController">
<div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="contacts">
            <div class="form-group multiple-form-group input-group">
                <div id="searchBrokerDropdown" class="input-group-btn input-group-select">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="concept">Broker Name</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Broker Name</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="hidden" class="input-group-select-val" name="contacts['type'][]" value="phone">
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="contacts['value'][]" class="form-control" data-ng-model="searchPhrase">
                <span class="input-group-btn searchButton">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" data-ng-click="$parent.search()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Partial("_Loading", new LoadingViewModel() { DisplayText = "Loading brokers..." })
        <div data-ng-show="!isBusy && !haveBrokers">
            <h3>No brokers found.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" data-ng-show="!isBusy && haveBrokers">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Brokers</h4>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <span class="clickable filter" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Filter Brokers" data-container="body">
                        <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-table-filter" data-action="filter" data-filters="#task-table" placeholder="Filter Tasks" />
            </div>
            <table class="table table-hover" id="task-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Broker Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="broker in brokers">
                        <td>{{ broker.Name }}</td>
                        <td data-ng-show="searchCriteria != 'PolicyNumberLike'"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View Policies</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried `ng-click="search()" ` ?

Comment: None we can see on the tiny bit of code you posted.

Comment: Yes tried ng-click, the button control is within a bootstrap modal, it seems to work when moved out of the modal, no idea why.

Comment: Modal has isolated scope. You should define the `search` function in the modal's controller instead

Comment: Perhaps this `<button>` tag is not inside the scope of your controller

Comment: Post modal configuration.

Comment: Yes, modal do have different scope, you need to have different controller for modal as well.

Comment: You don't need a different controller, you can specify `$scope` that modal will use without controller

Answer (score 0):

You have to check 2 things in that situation:

1. Check if your button is in the front (rise his z-index or check is :hover is working), maybe it is not on top so it can't be clickable.
2. Check if that buttont dont have own $scope (it is crated in subdirective, or in ng-repeat for example), in taht situation check:

   `<button type="button" data-ng-click="$parent.search()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>`

If that 2 things dosen't work check if any command ex. console.log('test_mode') will fire after click.

Comment: You should not reach for `$parent`, as it is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that the button is outside of controller scope, if you provide model with a specific controller you should put `search` function inside said controller, if you want to keep it in parent controller specify it like this:

```
$scope.modalFunctions = {
  search: function () {
    //do something
  }
}
```

then use `ng-click="modalFunctions.search"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the problem. My angular view is within a bootstrap wizard component (within a bootstrap modal) that I copied from [Bootsnipp](http://www.bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/ajax-div-wizard). The problem was with the javascript that was supplied,

```
wizardContent.html(currStep.html());
```

this piece of code replaced the wizard content with the HTML of the correct step. I modified the javascript to hide and show the correct steps instead of copying the HTML of the correct step to the div displayed to the user, which resolved the issue.