# ng-click not firing on a button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing weird error where I am not able to call a function on ng-click when button is clicked.

This is the block of code for which the ng-click is not working for delete button but working for edit button.

```
  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-bordered Pages_table">
                        <thead>
                            <td><b>Id</b></td>
                            <td><b>Image</b></td>
                            <td><b>Alt</b></td>
                            <td><b>Edit</b></td>
                            <td><b>Delete</b></td>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="dat in newData">
                                <td>((dat.id))</td>    
                                <td class="clients_review_admin_item"><img src="((imagePath+'/'+dat.image))" alt="" style="height:100px;width:150px" /></td>
                                <td>((dat.alt))</td>                                                    
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info rounded-buttons" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editWhy" ng-click="editWhy(dat)" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></td>
                                <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger rounded-buttons" type="button"   ng-click="deleteFooter(dat.id,dat.alt)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

The Javascript function deleteFooter

```
$scope.deleteFooter = function(id,name){
console.log("called");
     var postUrl = apiUrl+"/delfriendfooter";
      var $inputs = {
         id:id,
         token:$scope.token,
      };
     var func = function(){
                 $http.post(postUrl, $inputs).
                   success(function(data, status, headers, config) {        
                         swal("Deleted!", name+" has been deleted!", "success");     
                         var dat = $scope.newData;
                         for(var i=0,len= dat.length;i<len;i++){
                             if(dat[i].id==id){
                                 dat.splice(i,1);
                                 break;
                             }
                         }                                                                  
                   }).
                   error(function(data, status, headers, config) {        
                     sweetAlert("Oops!!", "Please try again!!", "error");
                   });
     }

 $scope.deletePopUp(func,name);
```

};

The weird thing is that it is working for the edit functionality

```
 <td><button class="btn btn-info rounded-buttons" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editWhy" ng-click="editWhy(dat)" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></td>
```

I have also tried to call other functions but it is just not firing.

Note: I have changed the angular braces to (()).

Comment: where is dat.id,dat.alt ???

Comment: Do you have both buttons in a form? Is the edit button the first of the two buttons?

Comment: are u getting errors in console?

Comment: no thats weird part.. no errors

Comment: ye @Cerbrus I have both buttons in form

Comment: Pass some test data instead of the two parameters, tell us if it works. I am guessing that's where the problem is.

Comment: @JqueryKing the dat is current data. I am using ng-repeat to populate the table.

Comment: @VSO I already tried that not working..

Comment: @Rujul1993: I'm pretty certain my answer should be the solution to the problem. Angular's behavior with buttons / forms isn't exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: Check if your curly brackets are matched properly. There is no ending bracket for deleteFooter.

Comment: @Sid the brackets are matched properly.

Comment: I have NO idea if this will do anything, this is random guessing, but try commenting out the function (just put a log or an alert in it or something) and pass dat, instead of properties of dat. (Obviously change parameters to one too).

Comment: @VSO I think the problem is with ng-click not even firing..If it fired and there were error related to function then angular would log it. And I did change the function name and tried lots of things but ng-click itself is not firing

Comment: @Rujul1993 Check again.

Comment: @Sid I edited the code in the questions.

Comment: is there deleteFooter and editWhy in same scope in same controller?

Comment: @cyan Yes they are both in same scope in same controller.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845474/ng-click-not-executing-controller-function this is this problem. Maybe problem with z-index?

Comment: @cyan I called other function using native js method onclick and it works. When I tried to use it to call the deleteFooter method using apply then it says that I cant perform dom operations using native js functions.

Comment: does a button work in that position in your markup if it has a different css class or a different icon?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of [the way angular / buttons / forms work](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action).

Specifically:

> To prevent double execution of the handler, use only one of the ngSubmit or ngClick directives. This is because of the following form submission rules in the HTML specification:
>
> - If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field triggers form submit (ngSubmit)
> - If a form has 2+ input fields and no buttons or `input[type=submit]` then hitting enter doesn't trigger submit
> - If a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or `input[type=submit]` then hitting enter in any of the input fields will trigger the click handler on the first button or `input[type=submit]` (`ngClick`) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (`ngSubmit`)

Because of these rules, buttons can behave a little strangely.

A solution is to add `type="button"` to your buttons. This will basically prevent these rules from being applied:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded-buttons"  ng-click="deleteFooter(dat.id,dat.alt)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
```

Angular will then, instead of using the form standards to decide what function to call, simply execute the `ng-click`'s function.

Comment: I already tried using the button type cause of the same fact that you posted. but didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a `action` on the form?

Comment: No. I am using tables. There is no form.

Comment: You just said you have a form... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406930/ng-click-not-firing-on-a-button-click/31407085?noredirect=1#comment50787754_31406930

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. But the problem is with ng-click not firing.

Comment: Even if you use an empty function?

Comment: I am going to back Cerbrus on this one. Pass two test parameters to an empty function. You need to rule this out.

Comment: @VSO as I am saying that no matter what function I pass the root problem is in ng-click not firing.. I already tried all the possible combination of functions and parameters. Its really frustating cause the console doesn't even logs the error as ng-click event have to fire first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i guess deleteFooter function and it's ng-click is called on different scopes. 
Both are defined in your controllers scope, and its fine. 
But i suppose, as You wrote, that you call deleteFooter in ng-repeat, which has its own scope.

Use $parent to enforce your controller scope on deleteFooter.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger rounded-buttons"  ng-click="$parent.deleteFooter(dat.id,dat.alt)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
```

Comment: Could you change deleteFooter to whatever simple function ( edit why etc. ) exactly in place of deleteFooter? in sam table row and col, to exclude situation with css.

Comment: so, exchanging worked in another dom section, but in this place didn't work?

Comment: Ya the edit button is just next to delete button which is working perfectly.

Comment: both are in ng-repeat loop?

Comment: Yes. Let me just post the whole html page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after so many efforts I opted for jquery ajax method and applied the changes using angular $apply to the scope variable. I am still not sure what is wrong.